# Executing BashScript with PHP Issues

Tags: php, bash, echo, execute

I have a bash script that's tied into some python scripts that I would like to execute within a webpage and cat the file it creates on to the page.  Currently I haven't been able to execute the script at all (tested the script multiple times to ensure it is in fact working), and I can't seem to find where my error is.  The first set of code is from my 'dashboard.php' file which is in /var/www. I have changed the permissions for the scripts to 777 and made executable.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    IP/CIDR Input: <input type="text" name="cidriptext" />
    Single IP: <input type="checkbox" name="singlech" value="single" /> 
    CIDR Range: <input type="checkbox" name="cidrch" value="cidr" />    
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    List of IP's: <input type="text" name="listname" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This second script is the page ('welcome.php') it reaches out to execute the script with the input from the form.  At this point I don't expect the `$listname_text` to work properly, but I do expect to get the 'Incorrect Input' error when no boxes are checked, the 'testing' output at the end, and the files being created on the backend.

```
<?php
    $ipcidr_text = $_POST['cidriptext'];
    $listname_text = $_POST['listname'];

    if !(empty($listname_text):
        shell_exec('/var/www/getStarted -l $ipcidr_text');
        $output0 = shell_exec('echo "List of IP's"');
        echo "<pre>$output0</pre>";

    elseif (isset($_POST['cidrch'])):
        shell_exec('/var/www/getStarted -c $ipcidr_text');
        $output1 = shell_exec('echo "CIDR Range"');
        echo "<pre>$output1</pre>";

    elseif (isset($_POST['singlech'])):
        shell_exec('/var/www/getStarted -s $ipcidr_text');
        $output2 = shell_exec('echo "Single IP"');
        echo "<pre>$output2</pre>";

    else:
        $output = shell_exec('echo "Incorrect input"');
        echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; 

    endif;

    $testing = shell_exec('echo "testing"');
    echo "<pre>$testing</pre>";

?>
```

PHP is working, I am able to execute a basic script:

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('echo "Incorrect"');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

If you need anymore information, please let me know.  Appreciate any help!

Comment: The relative path `./` is my guess. What's the current directory of the PHP process? I'd recommend full paths.

Comment: I changed to full path and still didn't work.  Wouldn't 'testing' and/or 'Incorrect input' still be echoed on the page regardless of path?

Comment: Do **NOT EVER** use this code in production. You are passing user-provided data directly to a shell. You risk having your server **TOTALLY** destroyed by the first person who passes in `; rm -rf /` via `$_POST['cirdiptext']`.

Comment: Appreciate the concern, but this will only be accessible internally to a controlled subset of users(3).  Adding to that, is there a better way to do it?  Obviously sanitizing input to accepting only a specific format would be useful, but is there something else that could be used instead of $_POST?

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues with `shell_exec()` in the past and tend to lean on `system()` instead, also try `"` instead of `'` to encapsulate the command.  You may also need to change how you call your script:

From:

```
/var/www/getStarted
```

To (call the python interpreter specifically):

```
/usr/bin/python /var/www/getStarted
```